# Ruby string method, can't make exception using .unless method

Tags: ruby

I'm working on changing letters of a string, 'e' to '3', 'o' to '0', 'I to '1' and 's' to 'z'. All my specs work but I can't figure out how to make an exception to 's'. If 's' is the first letter, it should not change. I've tried using .unless, but can't make it work. I've read multiple sites on how to implement .unless, but still can't make it work.

```
class String
  def altspeak
    new = []
    old = self.split("")
    old.each do |letter|
      if letter == "e"
        letter = "3"
        new.push(letter)
      elsif letter == "o"
        letter = "0"
        new.push(letter)
      elsif letter == "I"
        letter = "1"
        new.push(letter)
      elsif letter == "s"
        letter = "z"
        new.push(letter)
      else
        new.push(letter)
      end
    end
    new.join
  end
end
```

I've tried Variations of plugging .unless into the elsif, but I'm just guessing:

```
      elsif letter == "s"
        letter = "z"
        unless old.first == "s"
        new.push(letter)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no method named `unless` in any module or class in the Ruby core library or in the standard library.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag - Ah! You're right. I mispoke. It's late. I believe it would be called a conditional structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it.

```
elsif letter == "s"
    unless old.first == "s" && new.length.zero?
      letter = "z"
    end
    new.push(letter)
```

Comment: Excellent!! This works rohit. But, I don't understand why. I know .zero? returns true if num has a zero value, but I don't see the importance of the second condition. We're saying "unless the first letter/element in the old array is an 's', AND the length of the new array is 0", why does the length of the new array matter if we're just looking at the first element/letter of the old array of letters?

Comment: @Padawan: if new.length.zero is true, it means that this is the first character you are entering. Without this condition, all "s" letters will remain unchanged if the string starts with s.

Comment: K, thanks. This is helping, just wasn't intuitive for me. Will review and etch into brain pan tomorrow. Great thanks.

Comment: @Padawan: Its just another way of checking if `index == 0` without actually needing to use `each_with_index`.

Comment: A mistake in my clarification, each string in the array that begins with an 's' is supposed to keep the 's', not just the first 's' in the array. Your solution just works for the the first letter, any ideas?

Comment: @Padawan: Skip the `new.length.zero?` check.

Answer (score 2):

To test for first letter, use `each_with_index` instead of `each`:

```
old.each_with_index do |letter, index|
  ...
  elsif letter == "s" && index != 0
  ...
end
```

Tip: you don't need to use `split`, you could use `self.each_char.each_with_index`.

Advanced class:

```
class String
  def altspeak
    self.gsub /(?!^s)[eoIs]/ do |m|
      "301z"["eoIs".index(m)]
    end
  end
end

"somethings".altspeak
# => "s0m3thingz"
```

This will search for letters `e`, `o`, `I` and `s` within the string, but not if they are `s` at the beginning of string, then substitute them with their corresponding replacements.

Comment: Wow! Some good stuff here. Am going to have to look this over some more and practice. Thanks Amadan. But one question, would I simply add the 'old.each_with_index do...' after the main if/else/end statement?

Comment: No, the first snippet is a drop-in replacement for the two lines in your code (`old.each do |letter|` and `elsif letter == 's'`).

Comment: why not just use `gsub` with a `Hash` like `.gsub(/(?!^s)[eoIs]/, "e" => 3, "o" => 0, "I" => 1, "s" => "z")`? Same result without the need for the block.

Comment: @engineersmnky: Lol, didn't think of that. Yeah, that's the better way.